# Get JSON response from Jenkins API in java which requires sign in

Tags: json, jenkins

I want to read JSON response coming from jenkins API to read last build details. I am using http://jenkins_server/job/job_name/lastBuild/api/json. When I type this URL in browser, I need to sign in to my Jenkins job and after that I get proper json response.

I have written a java code to read JSON response from same Jenkins API. But I get "Server returned HTTP response code: 403" as I have not handled the authentication part in code.

```
 public class GetJSONResponse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL("http://jenkins_server/job/job_name/lastBuild/api/json").openStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        System.out.println(json.toString());

    }
}
```

I searched alot on how to get JSON response from jenkins API which reqiures authentication , but didn't find anything useful. How do I add authentication part in my code? Can anybody please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem after changing the jenkins config.xml "useSecurity" fileld.
Change `<useSecurity>true</useSecurity> to <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>`

And I got correct JSON response.